# animation transition based on position of cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I would like to know how to make a view/component/div/ANYTHING transition based on cursor movement for example...

say i have a blue div located at the bottom left of my screen and a red div located at the bottom right on my screen.
i want to make it so that when i move my mouse cursor towards the bottom left div it gradually transitions from blue to green based on how close the cursor gets, and the further the cursor gets the more it transitions back to its original color.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you tried to do it?

Comment: how do you do it ?

Comment: Listen to `mousemove` event to get the mouse cursor coordinates. Compare those coordinates to coordinates of divs. Update divs colors on the comparison result. Pretty easy, huh?

Comment: ive thought of that already.. the problem is how do you update divs colors on the comparison result

Comment: Adjust the values of the color components (red, green, blue) with javascript.

Comment: Please make an attempt and share it here. Don't wait till someone write the code for you.

Comment: how can i write the code to something i dont know how to do ?

Comment: changing the color of divs is just one of many i want to do.. i want to do this for view transitions ect

Comment: You can start from the small snippet (you can make it right in your question): make a page with two divs, one blue, one red, write a `mousemove` handler which calculates the distance between the mouse cursor and the divs. Then I and probably other people will be happy to help you with the rest.